# JetBrains template file | plural variable to singular

Tags: phpstorm, velocity, jetbrains-ide

How can I convert a plural form into singular (i.e `users` to `user`) in a file template of JetBrains IDE (PhpStorm) ?

I am looking for something like the following:

```
#set($SINGULAR= $PLURAL.toSingular())
```

Comment: File templates use Velocity. It can use Java's standard string functions. Does Java has such `toSingular()` function? I could not find any in my quick searches...

Comment: No, java has no `toSingular()`, Is there any way to convert plural form into singular in the file template?

Comment: I do not see anything built-in. Maybe GroovyScript has it? You can use Live Templates in File Templates (and GroovyScript can be used in Live Templates). Other than that: you can perform some simple find-and-replace oparations yourself (e.g. in most simple case: remove trailing `s` or alike).